# Restore scrollbar position of QWebView after setHtml()

Tags: qt, qtwebkit

I constantly generate new HTML pages that I display in a `QWebView`. Now I have trouble to restore the current position of the vertical scrollbar after the `setHtml()` call, if the HTML contains images. The scrollbar always jumps back to the top.

The following code works as long as the HTML only contains text:

```
void MainWindow::htmlResultReady(const QString &html)
{
     // remember scrollbar position
     int scrollBarPos = ui->webView->page()->mainFrame()->scrollBarValue(Qt::Vertical);

     ui->webView->setHtml(html);

     // restore previous scrollbar position
     ui->webView->page()->mainFrame()->setScrollBarValue(Qt::Vertical, scrollBarPos);
}
```

I also tried to use the signal QWebView::loadFinished() without success:

```
void MainWindow::setupHtmlPreview()
{
     connect(ui->webView, SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)),
             this, SLOT(restoreScrollBarPosition()));
}

void MainWindow::htmlResultReady(const QString &html)
{
     // remember scrollbar position
     scrollBarPos = ui->webView->page()->mainFrame()->scrollBarValue(Qt::Vertical);

     ui->webView->setHtml(html);
}

void MainWindow::restoreScrollBarPosition()
{
     // restore previous scrollbar position
     ui->webView->page()->mainFrame()->setScrollBarValue(Qt::Vertical, scrollBarPos);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the size of the page changes. Call `setScrollBarValue` when `contentsSizeChanged` is emitted by the frame (typically `webView->page()->mainFrame()`).